How do I get this iframe to resize according to content?
Having a devil of a time getting an iframe to resize according to its content. I've tried a bunch of different 'solutions' posted in forums, and now I'm using the solution at https://iframe-resizer.com/.
Here's the test page I'm working with: https://mcpirstaging.wpenginepowered.com/maine-legislature/
Here's the code on the parent page:


<iframe id="myIframe" src="https://george-mainemonitor.github.io/my-reps/" style="width: 100%;height: 100vh;border:none;"></iframe>

<script src="/wp-admin/js/iframe-resizer.parent.js"></script>
<script>
  iframeResize({ license: 'GPLv3', waitForLoad: true }, '#myIframe');
</script>



The iframe displays with a lot of empty whitespace on initial page load, and then when the user interacts with the content in the iframe (submits a form query) when the results load the iframe does not resize at all.
Not seeing any errors happening. Any idea what might be going on and how to resolve this? Thank you.

Try setting waitForLoad to false.

Thanks for the suggestion, that was one of the first things I tried. No effect at all.

Are you seeing any errors in the browser console?

Have you included the child package in the iframe page?

thanks, I've given up on making this work, spent way too much time on it and it seems that controlling iframes dynamically like I'm trying to do is a fool's errand. Will try another approach.
